# Tool for Scanning for Attached USB Devices in Windows

Tags: windows, usb, utilities, discovery

Can anyone recommend a (preferably free) tool for scanning for attached USB devices in a Windows environment?  This is for development purposes only.  I have a USB peripheral that I know works when it is attached to my system, but I'm having trouble finding it in the Device Manager.  I would like to be able to scan for it specifically because I am extending my application to support more than one type of USB device, but it's hard to scan for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would recommend you [devcon.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) utility (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272). The call

```
devcon.exe find USB\*
```

will show the information which you need. With respect of the utility you can do the most things which you can do with the Device Manager.

You can [download WDK](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/WDK/WDKpkg.mspx) (also known as DDK). After installation of of WDK look in C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\tools\devcon\i386 directory for the utility. Its source (if needed) you will find in C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\src\setup\devcon directories.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to download visual studio just to get devcon.exe, there's always [snoopypro](https://sourceforge.net/projects/usbsnoop/).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps USBDeview  from Nirsoft